# Why are two nearly identical DataSets behaving different?

Tags: c#, enums, dataset

i've got two DataSet with each one DataTable inside.

DataSet #1:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable(name);
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Customer Name",typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Contact Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Adress", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Postal Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
        string mem;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("| {0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4} | {5} |",
            table.Columns[1], table.Columns[2], table.Columns[3],
            table.Columns[4], table.Columns[5], table.Columns[6]);
        int count=1;
        do
        {
            table.Rows.Add(count, Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), 
                Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("if finished, type end");
            mem=Console.ReadLine();
            count++;
        }
        while (mem != "end");

        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        set.Tables.Add(table);
```

and DataSet #2:

("load" is DataSet #1)

```
        string srch = Console.ReadLine();
        string ask = "[Customer Name] like '%"+srch+"%' OR [Contact Name] like '%"+srch+"%' OR [Adress] like '%"+srch+"%' OR [City] like '%"+srch+"%' OR [Postal Code] like '%"+srch+"%' OR [Country] like '%"+srch+"%'";
        DataRow[] foundRows = load.Tables[0].Select(ask);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Customer Name",typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Contact Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Adress", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Postal Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
        foreach (DataRow item in foundRows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);
        }
        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        set.Tables.Add(dt);
```

When sending DataSet #2 to the function Print(), i get an error at "dtc.AsEnumerable()" 
with DataSet #1 everything works fine...

```
    static void Print(DataSet load)
    {
        DataTable dtc = load.Tables[0];
        List<int> maxlenght = Enumerable.Range(0, dtc.Columns.Count)
                                        .Select(col => dtc.AsEnumerable()
                                        .Select(row => row[col]).OfType<string>()
                                        .Max(val => val.Length)).ToList();

        //rest prints DataTable on a grid in console
    }
```

How can this be, while both DataSets are identical from structure?

Comment: What's the error? Are you sure `dtc` is not null?

Comment: Is not Dataset2 should have `dt` in place of `table`?

Comment: Does the range need to go from 0 to columns.count-1?

Comment: dtc is definively filled with data from Table1

Comment: Please don't post exception details in a comment.  Update your question instead.

Comment: problem solved through changing Print() into a more usual code, without these auto-creating loops.